# Implementing Virtual function C++

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

function in CefRequesthandler class (cef_request_handler.h):

```
virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {


    return RV_CONTINUE;

  }
```

Copied the function to the SimpleHandler class as shown below.

```
virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) OVERRIDE;
```

added the following to the SimpleHandler class file:

```
 #include "include/cef_request_handler.h"
```

I did not extend the CefRequestHandler class from the Simplehandler class. I do not think it is needed.

In my Simplehandler.cc file, I implement the function as shown below:

```
CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue SimpleHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback){

CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);


    return RV_CONTINUE;

}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no ‘CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue SimpleHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>, CefRefPtr<CefRequest>, CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback>)’ member function declared in class ‘SimpleHandler’
       CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback){
                                             ^
```

The `CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue` is derived from the following statement in the CefRequestHandler class:

`typedef cef_return_value_t ReturnValue`;

What am I missing that would cause the compiler to say `no member function declared in class ‘SimpleHandler’`?

simple_handler.h /SimpleHandler class

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#ifndef CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_HANDLER_H_
#define CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_HANDLER_H_

#include "include/cef_client.h"

#include "include/cef_request_handler.h"




#include <list>

class SimpleHandler : public CefClient,
                      public CefDisplayHandler,
                      public CefLifeSpanHandler,
                      public CefLoadHandler {
 public:
  explicit SimpleHandler(bool use_views);
  ~SimpleHandler();

  // Provide access to the single global instance of this object.
  static SimpleHandler* GetInstance();

  // CefClient methods:
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefDisplayHandler> GetDisplayHandler() OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefLifeSpanHandler> GetLifeSpanHandler() OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefLoadHandler> GetLoadHandler() OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }

  // CefDisplayHandler methods:
  virtual void OnTitleChange(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                             const CefString& title) OVERRIDE;

  // CefLifeSpanHandler methods:
  virtual void OnAfterCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) OVERRIDE;
  virtual bool DoClose(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) OVERRIDE;
  virtual void OnBeforeClose(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) OVERRIDE;

  // CefLoadHandler methods:
  virtual void OnLoadError(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                           CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                           ErrorCode errorCode,
                           const CefString& errorText,
                           const CefString& failedUrl) OVERRIDE;

virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) OVERRIDE;

//{ return false; }



  // Request that all existing browser windows close.
  void CloseAllBrowsers(bool force_close);

  bool IsClosing() const { return is_closing_; }

 private:
  // Platform-specific implementation.
  void PlatformTitleChange(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                           const CefString& title);

  // True if the application is using the Views framework.
  const bool use_views_;

  // List of existing browser windows. Only accessed on the CEF UI thread.
  typedef std::list<CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> > BrowserList;
  BrowserList browser_list_;

  bool is_closing_;

  // Include the default reference counting implementation.
  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(SimpleHandler);
};

#endif  // CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_HANDLER_H_
```

simple_handler.cc

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#include "cefsimple/simple_handler.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "include/base/cef_bind.h"
#include "include/cef_app.h"
#include "include/views/cef_browser_view.h"
#include "include/views/cef_window.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_closure_task.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_helpers.h"
#include "include/cef_request_handler.h"

namespace {

SimpleHandler* g_instance = NULL;

}  // namespace

SimpleHandler::SimpleHandler(bool use_views)
    : use_views_(use_views),
      is_closing_(false) {
  DCHECK(!g_instance);
  g_instance = this;
}

SimpleHandler::~SimpleHandler() {
  g_instance = NULL;
}

// static
SimpleHandler* SimpleHandler::GetInstance() {
  return g_instance;
}

void SimpleHandler::OnTitleChange(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  const CefString& title) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  if (use_views_) {
    // Set the title of the window using the Views framework.
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view =
        CefBrowserView::GetForBrowser(browser);
    if (browser_view) {
      CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window = browser_view->GetWindow();
      if (window)
        window->SetTitle(title);
    }
  } else {
    // Set the title of the window using platform APIs.
    PlatformTitleChange(browser, title);
  }
}

void SimpleHandler::OnAfterCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  // Add to the list of existing browsers.
  browser_list_.push_back(browser);
}

 CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue SimpleHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback){

CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);


    return RV_CONTINUE;

}

bool SimpleHandler::DoClose(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  // Closing the main window requires special handling. See the DoClose()
  // documentation in the CEF header for a detailed destription of this
  // process.
  if (browser_list_.size() == 1) {
    // Set a flag to indicate that the window close should be allowed.
    is_closing_ = true;
  }

  // Allow the close. For windowed browsers this will result in the OS close
  // event being sent.
  return false;
}

void SimpleHandler::OnBeforeClose(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  // Remove from the list of existing browsers.
  BrowserList::iterator bit = browser_list_.begin();
  for (; bit != browser_list_.end(); ++bit) {
    if ((*bit)->IsSame(browser)) {
      browser_list_.erase(bit);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (browser_list_.empty()) {
    // All browser windows have closed. Quit the application message loop.
    CefQuitMessageLoop();
  }
}

void SimpleHandler::OnLoadError(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                ErrorCode errorCode,
                                const CefString& errorText,
                                const CefString& failedUrl) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  // Don't display an error for downloaded files.
  if (errorCode == ERR_ABORTED)
    return;

  // Display a load error message.
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "<html><body bgcolor=\"white\">"
        "<h2>Failed to load URL " << std::string(failedUrl) <<
        " with error " << std::string(errorText) << " (" << errorCode <<
        ").</h2></body></html>";
  frame->LoadString(ss.str(), failedUrl);
}

void SimpleHandler::CloseAllBrowsers(bool force_close) {
  if (!CefCurrentlyOn(TID_UI)) {
    // Execute on the UI thread.
    CefPostTask(TID_UI,
        base::Bind(&SimpleHandler::CloseAllBrowsers, this, force_close));
    return;
  }

  if (browser_list_.empty())
    return;

  BrowserList::const_iterator it = browser_list_.begin();
  for (; it != browser_list_.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->GetHost()->CloseBrowser(force_close);
}
```

cef_request_handler.h Cefrequesthandler class

---

```
//
// The contents of this file must follow a specific format in order to
// support the CEF translator tool. See the translator.README.txt file in the
// tools directory for more information.
//

#ifndef CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_REQUEST_HANDLER_H_
#define CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_REQUEST_HANDLER_H_
#pragma once

#include "include/cef_auth_callback.h"
#include "include/cef_base.h"
#include "include/cef_browser.h"
#include "include/cef_frame.h"
#include "include/cef_resource_handler.h"
#include "include/cef_response.h"
#include "include/cef_response_filter.h"
#include "include/cef_request.h"
#include "include/cef_ssl_info.h"


///
// Callback interface used for asynchronous continuation of url requests.
///
/*--cef(source=library)--*/
class CefRequestCallback : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  ///
  // Continue the url request. If |allow| is true the request will be continued.
  // Otherwise, the request will be canceled.
  ///
  /*--cef(capi_name=cont)--*/
  virtual void Continue(bool allow) =0;

  ///
  // Cancel the url request.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void Cancel() =0;
};


///
// Implement this interface to handle events related to browser requests. The
// methods of this class will be called on the thread indicated.
///
/*--cef(source=client)--*/
class CefRequestHandler : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  typedef cef_return_value_t ReturnValue;
  typedef cef_termination_status_t TerminationStatus;
  typedef cef_urlrequest_status_t URLRequestStatus;
  typedef cef_window_open_disposition_t WindowOpenDisposition;

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before browser navigation. Return true to cancel
  // the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed. The |request|
  // object cannot be modified in this callback.
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadingStateChange will be called twice in all cases.
  // If the navigation is allowed CefLoadHandler::OnLoadStart and
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadEnd will be called. If the navigation is canceled
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadError will be called with an |errorCode| value of
  // ERR_ABORTED.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              bool is_redirect) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before OnBeforeBrowse in certain limited cases
  // where navigating a new or different browser might be desirable. This
  // includes user-initiated navigation that might open in a special way (e.g.
  // links clicked via middle-click or ctrl + left-click) and certain types of
  // cross-origin navigation initiated from the renderer process (e.g.
  // navigating the top-level frame to/from a file URL). The |browser| and
  // |frame| values represent the source of the navigation. The
  // |target_disposition| value indicates where the user intended to navigate
  // the browser based on standard Chromium behaviors (e.g. current tab,
  // new tab, etc). The |user_gesture| value will be true if the browser
  // navigated via explicit user gesture (e.g. clicking a link) or false if it
  // navigated automatically (e.g. via the DomContentLoaded event). Return true
  // to cancel the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed in the
  // source browser's top-level frame.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnOpenURLFromTab(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                const CefString& target_url,
                                WindowOpenDisposition target_disposition,
                                bool user_gesture) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource request is loaded. The |request|
  // object may be modified. Return RV_CONTINUE to continue the request
  // immediately. Return RV_CONTINUE_ASYNC and call CefRequestCallback::
  // Continue() at a later time to continue or cancel the request
  // asynchronously. Return RV_CANCEL to cancel the request immediately.
  //
  ///
  /*--cef(default_retval=RV_CONTINUE)--*/
  virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {

//CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
 // request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return RV_CONTINUE;

  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource is loaded. To allow the resource
  // to load normally return NULL. To specify a handler for the resource return
  // a CefResourceHandler object. The |request| object should not be modified in
  // this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> GetResourceHandler(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request) {

    return NULL;
    return new MyResourceHandler();
    //new MyResourceHandler();
  }

class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
{
public:
MyResourceHandler()
//offset_(0)
{}

  bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) {

    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
    request = cef;
    CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
    request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return true;
    //cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);};
};

   void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) ;


   bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;

  bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   void Cancel() ;

   void AddRef()const {} ;

bool Release() const { return true; }

 bool HasOneRef() const { return true; };

    //bool CefBase::HasOneRef();

    //void CefBase::AddRef() const;

 // bool ProcessRequest (CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
//CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback){

//CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
//cef = request;
//CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
//request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
//cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);

//}

//IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(MyResourceHandler);
//IMPLEMENT_LOCKING(MyResourceHandler);
};

//void AddRef();

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load is redirected. The |request|
  // parameter will contain the old URL and other request-related information.
  // The |new_url| parameter will contain the new URL and can be changed if
  // desired. The |request| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceRedirect(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefString& new_url) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource response is received. To allow the
  // resource to load normally return false. To redirect or retry the resource
  // modify |request| (url, headers or post body) and return true. The
  // |response| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnResourceResponse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread to optionally filter resource response content.
  // |request| and |response| represent the request and response respectively
  // and cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefResponseFilter> GetResourceResponseFilter(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return NULL;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load has completed. |request| and
  // |response| represent the request and response respectively and cannot be
  // modified in this callback. |status| indicates the load completion status.
  // |received_content_length| is the number of response bytes actually read.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceLoadComplete(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                      URLRequestStatus status,
                                      int64 received_content_length) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when the browser needs credentials from the user.
  // |isProxy| indicates whether the host is a proxy server. |host| contains the
  // hostname and |port| contains the port number. |realm| is the realm of the
  // challenge and may be empty. |scheme| is the authentication scheme used,
  // such as "basic" or "digest", and will be empty if the source of the request
  // is an FTP server. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefAuthCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time when
  // the authentication information is available. Return false to cancel the
  // request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef(optional_param=realm,optional_param=scheme)--*/
  virtual bool GetAuthCredentials(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  bool isProxy,
                                  const CefString& host,
                                  int port,
                                  const CefString& realm,
                                  const CefString& scheme,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefAuthCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when JavaScript requests a specific storage quota
  // size via the webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota function. |origin_url| is the
  // origin of the page making the request. |new_size| is the requested quota
  // size in bytes. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefRequestCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time to
  // grant or deny the request. Return false to cancel the request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnQuotaRequest(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              const CefString& origin_url,
                              int64 new_size,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an unknown
  // protocol component. Set |allow_os_execution| to true to attempt execution
  // via the registered OS protocol handler, if any.
  // SECURITY WARNING: YOU SHOULD USE THIS METHOD TO ENFORCE RESTRICTIONS BASED
  // ON SCHEME, HOST OR OTHER URL ANALYSIS BEFORE ALLOWING OS EXECUTION.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnProtocolExecution(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                   const CefString& url,
                                   bool& allow_os_execution) {}

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an invalid
  // SSL certificate. Return true and call CefRequestCallback::Continue() either
  // in this method or at a later time to continue or cancel the request. Return
  // false to cancel the request immediately. If
  // CefSettings.ignore_certificate_errors is set all invalid certificates will
  // be accepted without calling this method.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnCertificateError(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      cef_errorcode_t cert_error,
      const CefString& request_url,
      CefRefPtr<CefSSLInfo> ssl_info,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when a plugin has crashed.
  // |plugin_path| is the path of the plugin that crashed.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnPluginCrashed(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                               const CefString& plugin_path) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render view associated
  // with |browser| is ready to receive/handle IPC messages in the render
  // process.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderViewReady(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render process
  // terminates unexpectedly. |status| indicates how the process
  // terminated.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderProcessTerminated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                         TerminationStatus status) {}
};

#endif  // CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_REQUEST_HANDLER_H_
```

Comment: Post the header where SimpleHandler is declared?

Comment: I dunno, the declaration in the header `SimpleHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad` is somehow different than in the source file. Trying fully qualifying `CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue` in the header.

Comment: new to c++. I will figure out how to do that and report back

Comment: Mother fud, that's a lot of code. And you want OP to post more? How about asking for a [mcve] people?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleHandler is not derived from CefRequestHandler. Yet within the SimpleHandler ReturnValue is being used without the CefRequestHandler qualifier, where as in the function implementation ReturnValue is used with the  CrefRequestHandler qualifier. -- 
CrefRequestHandler::ReturnValue SimpleHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad .

This implies that the one of the base classes of SimpleHandler also declares the ReturnValue ( and is different from CrefRequestHandler  declaration ) and hence in the definition it uses the base class value and in the implementation it uses from CefRequestHandler , causing the mismatch.

Change definition to below.

```
virtual CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) OVERRIDE;
```

Comment: wish you were right. tried that and it still did not work. It must be somethign simple I am missing. I tried pulling the method form the CefRequestHandler but get unable to redefine error. I tried extending the CefRequestHandler class within SimpleHandler and that did nothing. I even removed one extended class that SimpleHandler uses and received no error for doing so when compiling.

Comment: I get the same error when I include or do not include the " CefRequestHandler::" in the OVERRIDE statement in simple_handler.h/SimpleHandler class

Comment: a workaround define and implement the function in the class  class SimpleHandler : public CefClient,
                      public CefDisplayHandler,
                      public CefLifeSpanHandler,
            ....  {  ..... CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue  OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback){

CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return RV_CONTINUE;

}  } ;

Comment: thank you so much. You were on the right path earlier as well. I was editing the wrong simple_handler.h file. It was the simple_handler.h file located in the binary and not the project location. just figured that out

Comment: okay great . was wondering if the override can  causing some issue too , the CefLifeSpanHandler is not the base class , but OnBeforeResourceLoad is set as override in the SimpleHandler class. Does any of its base class have the declaration its overriding ?

Comment: Yes, the OnBeforeResourceLoad function is in the CefRequesthandler base class [cef_request_handler.h][http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/cef_request_handler.h.html]  It's a virtual function but not pure virtual like so many other functions in the framework.  now that I know which simple_handler.h file is being compiled, I am going to extend the CefRequestHandler class from Simplehandler class & see if I can properly override just that one function. & finally set the referrer. I had and have so much to learn with c++. its much better at forcing me to learn OOP. than Java